# Get Yahoo weather in celsius via their API

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

Trying to make a query in [YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/). This one works fine:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid=1989965
```

But I want to get values in metric system (celsius), so I use this query:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid=1989965 and unit='c'
```

I get a null result:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2016-03-28T01:46:08Z",
  "lang": "ru",
  "results": null
 }
}
```

I could convert values by myself, but I hope I can make it work out of the box...

Answer (score 8):

Today I discovered, u='c' is worked. So, the answer for my own question would be:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid=1989965 and u='c'
```